# How to fix "failed with exit status 2" while installing scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python. I want to install scrapy because i am learning web scraping. I tried to install it using pip.

I did some research and found anaconda. I installed scrapy using it but due to some reason program wasn't working.

```
c:\users\boi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(203):
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or direc
tory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\boi\appdata\local\progr
ams\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.arg
v[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Boi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4p7adohd\\Twisted\
\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Boi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
4p7adohd\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__fil
e__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(
code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Boi\AppData\Local\T
emp\pip-record-k9lky1yy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed
--compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am really frustrated. I have tried every solution i could find but i couldn't install it. I'll really appreciate the help.

Comment: There is no need to install scrapy via anaconda. create a virtual environment and install scrapy directly in it (`pip install Scrapy`). It will work.

Comment: I have tried to install Scrapy in a virtualenv but still i am still getting the same error.

Comment: is python installed in the system properly?

Comment: Is that error from anaconda-installed Scrapy or pip-installed Scrapy?

Comment: It was from anaconda-installed, but i have fixed it.. i just installed build tools and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Anaconda creates It's environments in `C:/Users/Username/Anaconda2....` (possible variations depending on versions of Anaconda and Windows(Win10 and Anaconda2 in my case)).

> ```
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\boi\appdata\local\progr
> ams\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c
> ```

This path of python.exe - is direct sign that
 You are trying to launch your application on environment with pip-installed Scrapy (not  anaconda-installed Scrapy).